# Private key not installed Apple Distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain

I have been stuck on this part for hours when going through the process of submitting my app.

[image]

I've googled for a few hours now and these steps did not work:

- Restarting Xcode
- Restarting the Mac
- Creating a new certificate
- Locking and Unlocking the key chain
- Trying to email myself the p12 file and opening it again in the key chain

It's also clear to note that I am using only one computer for all this so I don't know how to ask the creator which is me for a copy of the private key.  It is possible I may have messed up on a step so any guidance on what I should do to resolve this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: I *think* I agree, the issue is in your keychain. Where is it installed when you look in Keychain Access? EDIT: I'm assuming you already have done something like (a) submitted something to the App Store successfully, (b) successfully installed this app on an actual device, or at least (c) narrowed it down to iCloud?

Comment: @dfd It appears that my certificates are installed in the login keychain and the distribution certificate is marked as valid and when opened has a private key with my name.  I'm still new to this, so is this information good enough?

Comment: @dfd Yes I have been able to test the app on my physical iOS device

Comment: Everything you state seems good to me. I last submitted an app (actually a few) on 5 January. It's fairly automatic, but yes, the certificates are about the worst for me. My last thought.... Are you able to *archive* and *upload*? Maybe I'm asking this wrong. Where *exactly* in the process are you failing? And yes, is this your first attempt at app submission?

Comment: @dfd Yea the certificates are a pain, but I eventually went with the manual route instead of automatic and got it working.  As for your question I was able to archive and upload it.

Comment: So you fixed your issue? If so, please post an answer! (It's not wrong to do that.) I'll gladly upvote it.